# Button masked transition

Tags: css, animation, hover, transition

I want a button hover transition using an (I think) mask in the background.

A button that in normal state has a white background and black letters would have a black background sliding in from the side on hover making the letters white on the go. Like so:

[image: Wanted button transition]

I got it working using a before and after pseudo:

```
.button--slide {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button--slide span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.button--slide:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(-100% - 35px);
  top: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
}

.button--slide:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -70px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 35px solid transparent;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
  border-top: 35px solid #000;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
}

.button--slide:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.button--slide:hover:before {
  left: 0;
}

.button--slide:hover:after {
  left: calc(100% - 35px);
}
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5arj1emx/

It's not quite how I want it: I would like the background to mask the letters like in the example so that the letters turn white as the black background slides over it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a background animation for both the pseudo element and the span and make the one of the span to color the text. I used a big transition time to better see the result;

```css
body {
  background-color: #efefef
}

.button--slide {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding:0;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button--slide span {
  display:block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease;
  color:transparent;
  font-weight:bold;
  background:linear-gradient(-45deg,#000 50%,#fff 0) right/220% 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  background-clip:text;
}

.button--slide:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(-45deg,transparent 50%,#000 0) right/220% 100% no-repeat;
  transition:  5s ease;
}

.button--slide:hover span,
.button--slide:hover:before {
  background-position:left;
}
```

```html
<button class="button--slide">
<span>SEE OUR GLOBES</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it.